Understanding the solution of a differential equation found with Fourier Transform
So this year I was taught to find specific solutions to differential equations using fourier transforms.
If I have an equation like
$$a f^{\prime \prime}(x) + bf^\prime (x) + cf(x) = g(x)$$
I can take the fourier transform from both sides of the equation and apply its properties
$$-k^2a F(k) + ik b F(k) + c F(k) = G(k)$$
Solving for $F(k)$ you get
$$F(k) = \frac{G(k)}{-k^2a + ikb + c}$$
So theoretcally now I can just take the inverse transform to find a solution for $f(x)$
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dk \frac{G(k)}{-k^2a + ikb + c} e^{ikx}$$
And, if I understand correctly, the f(x) found should be one solution of the differential equation.
The problem I have with this method is that it finds a single function that satisfies the equation while there's an infinity of them; so I'm eager to know why it is that specific solution that comes out, why not another? Is there a way I can find other ones using the same method?

This is the solution that has a classical Fourier transform. You can also add to it any solution of the homogeneous ($g=0$) equation.

Sometimes solving things in the space of distributions will include the homogeneous parts.
For example, consider $y''+y=0.$ Taking the Fourier transform gives $-k^2Y+Y=0,$ i.e. $(1-k^2)Y=0.$ This has distribution solutions $Y(k)=A\delta(k+1)+B\delta(k-1),$ where $A,B$ are constants. Taking the inverse Fourier transform then gives the solutions
$y(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi} Ae^{-ix}+\frac{1}{2\pi} Be^{ix}.$

Thank you so much! I tried looking up the distribution solutions you wrote but didn't find an explanation as to why Y(k) should be a sum of two deltas, can I ask you to help me on that too? Also, what are the distribution solutions when the characteristic polinomial only has one solution?

@GauthierRuberti. Short explanation: if $f(k)$ has zeroes of order 1 at $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ then $f(k) Y(k) = 0$ has distribution solutions $Y(k) = a_1 \delta(x-a_1) + \cdots + a_n \delta(x-a_n).$ Note that the factor $(1-k^2)$ has zeroes of order 1 at $\pm 1.$
